How to format date in a chart in azure workbooks?
I'm trying to plot the response of cost management API of azure as a line chart in my azure workbook with a query of Azure Resource Manager data source. My x-axis is UsageDate and y-axis is PreTaxCost.
Default format of UsageDate given by the API is YYYYMMDD, but when I try to plot my date is being shown as YY,YYM,MDD.
How to remove these commas or format it to datetime?
I've tried to make units None and unchecked the show grouping separators in chart settings for X-axis, but the issue still persists.


How to format date in a chart in azure workbooks?

To format date in you can use format_datetime() function as below:
let rith = datatable(TestDate: string, Cost: real)
[
    "20240901", 68,
    "20240902", 69,
    "20240903", 70
];
rith
| extend Test_Date_Formatted = format_datetime(todatetime(TestDate), "yyyy,MM,dd")
| project Test_Date_Formatted, Cost
| render linechart

Output:

To remove commas:
changed the query to | extend Test_Date_Formatted = format_datetime(todatetime(TestDate), "yyyyMMdd")
Output:

